# AutoCompleteTextview Color set white by default

Tags: android, colors, autocompletetextview

I used an AutoCompleteTextView in my android app and it is working correctly. The only problem I am facing is that the color of the suggestions is white by default that is i am not able to see any suggestions. So when i start typing something the list expands with white entries(invisible), but when i click on any item i find that it is working as it should be. Only the color seems to be the problem. I am using the following code.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/location"  android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></AutoCompleteTextView>
```

and

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> autoadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,cities);
            city = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
            city.setAdapter(autoadapter);
            city.setThreshold(1);
            city.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is??
-Thanks in advance

Comment: I have solved the same problem by following this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11787982/1265456

Comment: This may not be a bug. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23969054/1013923) also and my comment under it.

Comment: Checkout my new answer that support `lollipop` versions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This a logged bug,

You can find some ways to fix it in the same link.

[Auto complete text view bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237)

[Bug solution](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237#c8)

**Note:** This solution will not work with `lollipop`

I hope it helps...

Comment: This answer wouldn't really help if those links broke. It's worth updating the answer to include details of the linked solution.

Answer (score 13):

I tried setting up the theme before setcontext, tried different resources parameter in arrayAdapter and tried different theme ,but nothing helped.

Then I changed the context from 'this' to 'getApplicationContext' but the problem was persistent.

Finally I changed the context parameter to "getBaseContext()" and the problem was solved.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. getBaseContext() can cause a memory leak and getApplicationContext() WILL cause a leak.

Answer (score 9):

For **Lollipop**, all the work around solutions in the reported [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237) will not work.

I finally reached a solution that works with `lollipop` and the previous OS versions by using `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` with the `adapter` instead as the following:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, suggestionList);
```

This will solve the White text issue without any need to change Theme attributes or anything.

Comment: @Amaresh I tried it by myself .. make sure you are using the previous snippet correctly .. and If you still have a problem with it, share your code, so we can try to figure out the problem together :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `simple_list_item_1` in `ArrayAdapter`,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> autoadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cities);
            city = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
```

Another solution is to quit the style in `AndroidManifest.xml`

**NOTE:** This solution does not work with `lollipop` OS versions

Answer (score 3):

Well, we can't set the "suggestion text" color, but we can change its background! Just use `android:popupBackground="YOUR_COLOR_HEX"` as in this example:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autocompletetextview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint=" ... "
        android:popupBackground="#000000"/>
```

Works also on Lollipop! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use

`setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);` **before** `setContentView`

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Set background color of pop up as`city.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.color.indicator);`

Answer (score 1):

if anyone still have the same issue

This worked for me

```
autocompleteF.setBackgroundColor(color.black);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme:

```xml
<item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me First use this **before** setContentView()

```
setTheme(android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Medium_Inverse);
```

you have to change some colors in colors.xml in the values folder