# AutoCompleteTextView background/foreground color

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on AutoCompleteTextView.Its working fine but the dropdown text is always white text on white background.
this picture explain my problem

picture explain my problem

[image]

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    >
    <!-- <AutoCompleteTextView  -->
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Tapez votre 1texte"
        android:textColor="#000"        
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
view = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.text);        
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,data);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);//dd
view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Try setting the background of the AutoCompleateTextView to black as well and see if that helps.

Comment: yeah it's working ,but how i can  change  items color , it's always white

Comment: Just use "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" instead of "android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line"

Answer (score 33):

If you want to change the look of the dropdown items change the XML layout you pass to the ArrayAdapter, (in your case this is `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`).

Lets make a new layout named `my_list_item.xml` in `res/layout`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
    android:textColor="#00f" />
```

This text is smaller, blue, and centered. I don't recommend using this layout, it's more to demonstrate that you can customize it.

Now use this instead:

```
view = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.text);        
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_list_item, data);
view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When you set attributes here (like the text color):

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Tapez votre 1texte"
    android:textColor="#000"        
    />
```

You are only changing the box above the dropdown list (the box that you see before you interact with the AutoCompleteTextView).  Hope that helps!

Comment: If you dont want to create custom adapter
Just use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" instead of "android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`

Answer (score 12):

This question might be old but I believe this is very important for me to share.
I had been experiencing the same problem as OP but it is because I was using 'getApplicationContext()' in place of 'this'

**Wrong**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PLACES);
```

**Correct**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PLACES);
```

Comment: If the adapter initialization is inside another thread or runnable then instead of using `getApplicationContext()` use `YourActivityName.this` instead. This will bring the text color back to default black from white.

Comment: Thank you so much, This fixed it for me, the answer should be updated to add this alternative.

Comment: Also, when your in  Fragment, you can just use `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky solution for this is:
 Add this line
**setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);** before `setContentView()` in your activity file in which your autocompletetextview is present. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Just use "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" instead of "android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line" n solve proble

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting up the theme before setcontext, tried different resources parameter in arrayAdapter and tried different theme ,but nothing helped.

Then I changed the context from 'this' to 'getApplicationContext' but the problem was persistent.

Finally I changed the context parameter to "getBaseContext()" and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

i got my solution in slecting layout of "select_dialog_singlechoice
        `ArrayAdapter<String > s1= new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice,state);`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9O2f.png)

instead of get application context write "this" in ArrayAdapter<>;

try using different layouts u will definately solve your queries

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing a simple tricky Way,

**Just change the Theme of your activity declared in your AndroidManifest.xml as**,

```
 <activity
   android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

**and in the Activity as follows**,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, arraylist);
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer by didldum https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237

workaround by extending the theme and overriding the 2 styles for the typed text and the suggest text:

1. use an extended theme in your manifest:
   ...

   ...
2. create the new theme (res/values/themes.xml) which uses fixed styles:
   ...

       @style/AutoCompleteTextViewLight
       @style/Widget.DropDownItemLight

   ...
3. create the styles (res/values/styles.xml) which fix the color:
   ...

       @android:color/primary_text_light


       @android:color/primary_text_light