# How to give colors for autocompletetextview in android?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

How to give colors for autocompletetextview in android.
I am using these two colors for background and text-color

android:background = "#000000"
android:textclolor = "#ffffff".

But the problem is if i type some texts on autocompletetextview then the listable values are showing in white color and same to the text-colors too.

I can't able to fix only a color for the whole autocompletetextview. How to do this?

suggestions please!..

thanks in advance

Comment: Read about custom themes. You can do it by same.

Comment: I had the same problem, but this guys had save me;
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11787982/1265456

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use ***android:popupBackground*** attributes in AutoCompleteTextView in layout xml. it works for your problem. 
As for example like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:popupBackground="#ffffff"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it at runtime like

```
 AutoCompleteTextView searchView = ... 
searchView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorId)));
```

and if you want to hange it in your `xml` file then you have to give
`android:popupBackground` property to your Autocomplete view.

enjoy your code:)

Answer (score 0):

To set the popup background use popupBackground xml property for [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html). I also advice you to use Themes for text colors, sizes etc. When you want to style a list on the AutoCompleTextView popup (for example change a divider) you can do it from theme settings like that:

```
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyListViewStyle</item>
```