# suggested words in autocomplete not visible?

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview

when i try to use autocomplete textview it works but all the suggested words have white color and when i clicked on them it s possible to see what is that suggestion

what should i do for this problem?

[image]

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/etBrand"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:hint="Brand"
      android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black" />
```

what should i add to this xml code to solve this problem?
thanks in advance...

Comment: private static final String[] Brands = new String[] {"Brand1","Brand2","Brand3","Brand4","Brand5",};
               ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBrand = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Brands);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This a logged bug,
>
> You can find some ways to fix it in the same link.
>
> [Auto complete text view
>   bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237)
>
> [Bug
>   solution](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237#c8)
>
> I hope it helps...

**source**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8471078/1932105

please use the search before asking next time.