# textColor of my AutoCompleteTextView is always white

Tags: java, android, xml, autocompletetextview

For some reason, no matter what I do the text coming up in my AutoCompleteTextView is always white. I've explicitly set textColor to black in my XML. I'm wondering if android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is white by default?

**Here is where I set up my ArrayAdapter:**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
                    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchUserTextField);
                    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Here is my XML:**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:hint="@string/search_user"
            android:id="@+id/searchUserTextField"
            android:ems="150"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:maxLines ="4"
            android:maxLength ="150"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:capitalize="none"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/submitSearch"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/submitSearch" />
```

Comment: Does [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470804/autocompletetextview-color-set-white-by-default) help you? Try it!

Comment: Try this one for the solution  [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787057/autocompletetextview-background-foreground-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked like its a logged bug in AOSP. You can find some more information as well as workarounds in this post [AutoCompleteTextview Color set white by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8470804/3474528)

Comment: Yeah looks like I'll have to do some digging, but that's great to know that this is actually a logged bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, in case someone is still looking for an answer that works as it is not a bug but you can provide your custom layout for autocomplete suggestions as follows:

**Change this line of code**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
```

**to**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_autocomplete, strings);
```

Make a layout resource file as **custom_autocomplete.xml** and provide required settings. Working template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:paddingVertical="15dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the default layout for drop down item view to your own custom layout containing only TextView:

Example ( In Kotlin )-

Replace android.R.layout.select_dialog_item in the line:

```
val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,gender)
```

To:

```
val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_drop_down,gender)
```

where gender is :

```
private var gender :Array<String> = arrayOf("Male", "Female", "Others")
```

Here is the custom layout file :
item_drop_down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/appBlue"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingStart="14dip"
android:paddingEnd="15dip"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textSize="@dimen/sp_15"
/>
```

Hope this might help somebody!
Happy Coding :)