# AutoCompleteTextView items' text not visible

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I'm loading an `AutoCompleteTextView` with lots of items but none of them is shown/visible in the popup.

P.s.: If I click somewhere in that empty white view, the text appears in the AutoCompleteTextView (it's white text)

`resource.xml`

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/reg_city"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
            android:hint="Città"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_register"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />
```

`activity.java`

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> citta_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_cities);
    in_city.setAdapter(citta_adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the suggestions are white-on-white, which is why you're not seeing them, but pressing on a suggestion works.

See this for a list of possible solutions: [AutoCompleteTextview Color set white by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470804/autocompletetextview-color-set-white-by-default)

Comment: I switched from getApplicationContext to getBaseContext and the problem solved, thank you

Comment: try to avoid using getApplicationContext, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298955/819355

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion